# Should proper nouns be transcribed with Esperanto letters or not?

Tags: nouns

Should proper nouns be transcribed with Esperanto letters or not? For example "Gia" (Italian name): Do I write "Ĝia" or "Ĝiao" or "Giao" or "Gia"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The tradition within [UEA](https://uea.org) is to transscribe the names of towns where [UKs](https://uea.org/kongresoj) are held. Also the names of famous esperantists are usually transcribed or they have taken an Esperanto name.

I would say that for others, it depends. The more pronunciation differs from the Esperanto pronunciation, the better is the idea to transcribe.

Take for instance the Italian esperantist [Gian Carlo Fighiera](https://eo.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gian_Carlo_Fighiera). If he does not have an Esperanto name, you can write "Gian" and provide a pronunciation hint, e.g. "Gian [Ĝian]". Or you can fully go with the transcribed version using a stipulative introduction "Gian, poste en formo Ĝian laŭ elparolado". But it really depends on the situation.

Names written in non-Latin-based writing systems, for instance the former emperor [嘉靖](https://eo.wikipedia.org/wiki/%C4%9Cia%C4%9Ding), are always latinized into form that follows pronunciation, so Ĝiaĝing. Here you can use an introduction like "Ĝiaĝing (ĉine 嘉靖, piĝine: Jiājng)" like they have done in Wikipedia.

Comment: So, what do you suggest? "Ĝiao" or "Ĝia" ?

Comment: it seems there is not the same way. look these wikipedia pages.

https://eo.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gian_Carlo_Fighiera

https://eo.wikipedia.org/wiki/%C4%9Cia%C4%9Ding

Comment: I added those two examples.

Comment: In my opinion, if the only change needed to esperantize a name is adding a hat ^ (as in the example given), I think it's OK to add it without sweating over the details, so Ĝia. On the other hand, if you changed J to Ĝ (or kept the J but changed the pronunciation as it is done with some “classic” names, like John → Johano), then I'd write a longer note as suggested: “originala: John, prononco: Ĝon, ktp”.

Comment: @marcus, except that pronunciation-wise "g" and "ĝ" stand quite apart – up to the point that you can say that they have nothing in common.

Comment: That's exactly why I said adding the hat is good: it's a tiny change in spelling to keep the original pronunciation.

Answer (score 0):

Historically there was a tendency (idealism) to Esperantize names, and in case of say the bible it was apt and unavoidable.

Nowadays a more modest approach is to let the latin names as they are (and also not accusativized): **Gia**. Following the transcription of non-latin scripts I think non-misforming accents are possible: **Ĝia**. Especially where the pronunciation is probably unfamiliar to the reader. **Ĝon** for **John** forms a secret language. Or better (as possible for all names) make a footnote of the phonetic pronunciation. Anything else would have needed a footnote for the original name!

Only in settings without couleur locale, like in a school play, a short story in any city, one might consider invented, hence Esperanto names, where **Johano** might be more appealing than **Johannes** or better prononciable.

Geographic names are a bit more Esperantized, though not for village level names. This is not uncommon in other languages: *Liège/Luik/Lüttich, Aachen/Aken, Nijmegen/Nimwegen.*